# Run VS Code debugger as root in c++ for gdb

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb

I've seen some answers for other languages, but I have yet to find an answer for gdb C++. I'd like to configure my json to run the debugger as root. What field do I have to add? I have it debugging as my user right now.

Comment: You likely don't need to run it as root.

Comment: I do, it needs to edit files with root privileges.

Comment: Then for the purpose of debugging, why not just launch Code as root?

Comment: Making all of my development files root seems like a pain. For a shared git repository doesn't that have consequences?

Comment: You'd be launching the editor as root, giving anything it does root privilege. Editing files with root privileges has consequences too.

Comment: @sweenish is this the only way?

Comment: I couldn't say, as I've never needed to this. You could always look up the documentation for `launch.json` and see if there's a field you can enable for root privilege.

Comment: @sweenish There seems to be for other languages (Python/Java) but I can't find one for C++, which makes me think I missed something, hence the question.

Comment: launch.json is a a JSON file. The keys that are available are (mostly) language-agnostic. Also: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug

Comment: And from that page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference

Comment: I used this to set up my debugging environment originally and I've searched it for 'sudo' and other permission keywords but I can't find anything for c++.